# Formatting error in indented bullet list with sublist and non-list members

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

The following renders incorrectly for me:

- A bulleted list item

  - A bulleted sub-list

  ... followed by a paragraph which is indented to be underneath the top-level bulleted list.

Here's how it's currently rendered in Chrome on MacOS High Sierra. Notice the large vertical empty space between the top-level bullet point and the sub-bullet:

> [image: Screen shot illustrating the rendering]

Comment: For what it's worth, this page renders just fine in Safari on my phone (iPhone SE, IOS 12.1.3).

Comment: I've got the same rendering-results as in the picture in Firefox 64.0.2 on macOS Mojave

Comment: Same output as in the screenshot in Firefox 60.4.0 on Linux.

Comment: The same output on Win 10 64-bit Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Comment: I'm not sure what you are considering incorrect here. The second paragraph is properly indented under the top-level bulleted list item. Your use of `...` makes it difficult to determine that. If you use the same text in both paragraphs, they line up.

Comment: @Makyen It's the vertical space between the first and the second bullet point. It would probably be fine at the end of a bulleted list, nut at the beginning, it looks like a glitch.

Comment: Ahh.. That. It's been that way for a long time, IIRC. When you add an additional paragraph to the top level `<li>` (the extra blank line), the first "paragraph" gets wrapped in a `<p>`, which triples the space between those first two lines. It's a 1.5em gap caused by the top level `<li>` using a `<p>` to hold "A bulleted list item". That `<p>` has `margin-bottom: 1em;` (because it's not `ul p:last-of-type`, which would get `margin-bottom: 0;`). The 2nd level `<ul>` has `padding-top: .5em;`. So, 1.5em total.  (continued)

Comment: Something similar happens with the same Markdown on GitHub. On GitHub, that extra blank line introduces even more vertical space, as all text in subsequent top level `<li>` are enclosed in `<p>`. The real problem, going by what GitHub does, is that SE requires the extra empty line. On GitHub, the empty blank line is not required to add the second line of text under the top level `<li>`. You can just use the properly indented HTML comment as the break from the 2nd level `<ul>`. Doing so results in the contents of the `<li>`s *not* being wrapped in `<p>`.